# How to add capability for clearSystemFiles

Tags: appium, appium-android

I've created a Web APP for Installation of builds in Native Mobiles.
It is working fine but getting below message in the console of cmd saying;

[debug] ←[35m[AndroidDriver]←[39m **Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystem
Files` capability if wanted.**

Can you please help me out on how to pass this in my code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty easy to do. Just like you provide [desired capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) add another one:

`DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("clearSystemFiles", true);`

If you are curious what this capability actually does you can see it in [appium-android-driver](https://github.com/appium/appium-android-driver/blob/master/lib/driver.js#L430) repo

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `clearSystemFiles` capability is optional. The message you're seeing is just informative.

If you want to use that capability you can add another line in your set of capabilities in your code like,

```
caps.setCapability (MobileCapabilityType.CLEAR_SYSTEM_FILES, true);
```